# F# WebApi Cors doesn't work

Tags: f#, cors, asp.net-web-api2, unauthorized

I'm trying to create a WebApi project written in `F#` and to enable `CORS`.
The Controller:

```
type DoItController() =
    inherit ApiController()

    [<EnableCors(origins = "*", headers = "*", methods = "Get")>]
    [<HttpGet>]
    [<Route "api/GetGenerateExcel">]
    member __.GetGenerateExcel() =
        async {
            // Some code
            return "It works"

        } 
        |> Async.StartAsTask


}
```

Open it directly from the browser it works. Calling it using `AngularJS` or plain `Javascript` I get `401`.

The equivalent controller in C# works:

```
public class DoItController : ApiController
    {
        [EnableCors("*", "*", "Get")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/GetGenerateExcel")]
        public async Task<string> GetGenerateExcel()
        {
            //Some code
            return "It works"
        }
    }
```

I also checked the `Global.asax`, they also match:

```
type Global() =
    inherit HttpApplication()

    static member RegisterWebApi(config: HttpConfiguration) =

        config.EnableCors()
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter) |> ignore

    member x.Application_Start() =
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action<_> Global.RegisterWebApi)

public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {
                config.EnableCors();
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            });
        }
    }
```

I checked all the nuget package, they match. Also the web.config doesn't have differences that could affect the functionality.

What else could I check or test?

EDIT:
The following is my Javascript part, it works if `withcredentials = true` is added (and also on the server):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);

request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Success!
    }
}

request.onerror = function() {
    //Error
}

request.send();
```

AngularJS:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response){
    // Success!
}, function(error){
   // Error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I did mine a little different, but i believe the same concept applies.  Mine is in c# as well, so disregard those differences.

In my WebApiConfig.cs

```
 using System.Web.Http.Cors;

 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");

 cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
 config.EnableCors(cors);
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

When i access with jQuery or JavaScript, I am required to send the following with my jQuery request.  It is what authorizes the user to access.

```
xhrFields : {withCredentials: true}
```

I don't use any of the code in the Global.asax as you did as that is where i register all of my config stuff that points to the associated classes in the App_Start folder.

My globabl.asax looks like this

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Just a note, i personally used the approach of having a xml file where i store the authorized domains that can access the webapi application.  Codes a bit different, but i can post it if it would help anyone.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to use `{withCredentials: true}`

Comment: @Emaborsa gotcha.  can you post an example of your js

Comment: added in the question

Comment: @Emaborsa can you actually do this without using the withCredentails? I get the same results as you if i try to make a request via js without using it.  maybe the 401 is actually  proper as the server where you are running your code isn't allowing anonymous access to it.

Comment: I have many C# Projects where it works without it. Furthermore, I have also one F# project where it works without, but can't find differences.

Comment: The part where you said it works with withCredentails and also on the server, can you check if that works but run it not on the server.  that way you could try to see where exactly the problem is occurring.  if it works, then we know the problem is related to anonymous access and the application.  if it isn't working, then we can see that it is still related to cross origin.

Comment: Could it be that the required authentication mechanism is different when not using `withCredentials`?

Comment: ....I'm an idiot. I disabled the anonymous authentication from the project properties. Once enabled, it works like a charm.